# Uploading files to an FTP server via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp

I need to upload a set of `.txt` files to an FTP server using a `.bat` file. So far, I've managed to connect to the FTP server, including the correct directory that I need to put the file into and then disconnect. However, it isn't uploading the files.

In my `.bat` file, I've got this line to start the process

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

Then, in `ftp.txt`, I've got

```
open my.ip.address
myUserName
myPassword
binary
cd myDir
cd myDir
put C:\MyFolder\*
quit
```

It goes to the correct directory when I run the batch file, the output being

> OK. Current directory is /myDir/MyFolder
>
> ftp> put C:\MyFolder*
>
> Error opening local file C:\MyFolder..
>
> ftp> quit
>
> Goodbye. You uploaded and downloaded 0 kbytes.

Why is it erroring when trying to upload all files from `C:\MyFolder\`? Is there another way to upload all of the files from a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`put` is used for a single file. To upload multiple files, use `mput` instead.

```
mput C:\MyFolder\*
```

You may also want to put a `prompt` on the line before the `mput` line so that you aren't prompted to press Y for each file in the folder.

Comment: Thanks! Currently when it's uploading the file it shows the command prompt window, which I don't want it to do. How do I hide this?

Comment: @David That's a completely separate question, so ask it separately. Plus you need to tell us, how do you run the `.bat` file.